# Do not display the gridline and the header row in Dojo DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I have been using the examples from this site ( 
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/datagrid/) to render the data. However, I don't want to display the gridline and the header row in Dojo Datagrid.

Could somebody give me some hints on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the header use

```
  #YOURGRIDID.dojoxGridHeader  { display:none; }
```

In the link mentioned, there are no gridlines.